# Should I review the question as requires editing when there is a signature?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, signatures

Many posts from newer users, and with that, many posts that land in the triage queue, have something attached in the end like "thank", "thanks in advance" or some signature.

This doesn't make the question worse. It just has some noise in it. Should I directly tag it as requires editing when the rest of the question is good?

Or should I just leave it, because it harms noone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would directly edit the question and remove this kind of noise. You can directly jump to the question from the triage queue and do it *right now*.